# What is the maximum duration value (CFTimeInterval) for a CAAnimationGroup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-animation, caanimation

I have two rotation animations in my `CAAnimationGroup`, one that starts from zero and another that repeats and autoreverses from that state:

```
- (void)addWobbleAnimationToView:(UIView *)view amount:(float)amount speed:(float)speed
{
    NSMutableArray *anims = [NSMutableArray array];

    // initial wobble
    CABasicAnimation *startWobble = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    startWobble.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-amount];
    startWobble.duration = speed/2.0;
    startWobble.beginTime = 0;
    startWobble.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    [anims addObject:startWobble];

    // rest of wobble
    CABasicAnimation *wobbleAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    wobbleAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-amount];
    wobbleAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:amount];
    wobbleAnim.duration = speed;
    wobbleAnim.beginTime = speed/2.0;
    wobbleAnim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    wobbleAnim.autoreverses = YES;
    wobbleAnim.repeatCount = INFINITY;
    [anims addObject:wobbleAnim];

    CAAnimationGroup *wobbleGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    wobbleGroup.duration = DBL_MAX; // this stops it from working
    wobbleGroup.animations = anims;

    [view.layer addAnimation:wobbleGroup forKey:@"wobble"];
}
```

Since CFTimeInterval is defined as a double, I try setting the duration of the animation group to `DBL_MAX`, but that stops the animation group from running. However, If I set it to a large number, such as 10000, it runs fine. What is the largest number I can use for a duration of a `CAAnimationGroup`, to ensure it runs for as near to infinity as possible?

**UPDATE:** It appears that if I put in a very large value such as `DBL_MAX / 4.0` then it freezes for a second, then starts animating. If I put in the value `DBL_MAX / 20.0` then the freeze at the beginning is a lot smaller. It seems that having such a large value for the duration is causing it to freeze up. Is there a better way of doing this other than using a very large value for the duration?

Comment: You're trying to make this group of animations repeat forever?

Comment: yes, but I only want the second part of the group to repeat forever.

Comment: Are you sure you need to set the duration at all? What happens if you leave it unset?

Comment: if I leave it unset, the animation doesn't run at all. Also, the way I have it set up, if the app enters the background and then is reopened, the animation stops, which is also a problem.

Comment: Um, `DBL_MAX` represents something on the order of 10^300 years.  `10000` represents over 2 hours.  How long do you expect your app to run before terminating?

Answer (score 1):

I am faced with the exact same issue right now... I hope someone proves me wrong, but the only reasonable way I see to handle this situation is by moving the first animation to a `CATransaction`, and chaining that with the autoreverse animation using:

```
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:block];
```

It's not ideal, but gets the job done.

Regarding your question about the animations being paused when coming back from background, that's a classic limitation of the CoreAnimation framework, many solutions have been proposed for it. The way I solve it is by simply reseting the animations at a random point of the animation, by randomizing the `timeOffset` property. The user can't tell exactly what the animation state should be, since the app was in the background. Here is some code that could help (look for the `//RANDOMIZE!!` comment):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(startAnimating)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                           object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];

...

for (CALayer* layer in _layers) 
{
    // RANDOMIZE!!!
    int index = arc4random()%[levels count];
    int level = ...;
    CGFloat xOffset = ...;

    layer.position = CGPointMake(xOffset, self.bounds.size.height/5.0f + yOffset * level);

    CGFloat speed = (1.5f + (arc4random() % 40)/10.f);
    CGFloat duration = (int)((self.bounds.size.width - xOffset)/speed);

    NSString* keyPath = @"position.x";
    CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:keyPath];

    anim.fromValue      = @(xOffset);
    anim.toValue        = @(self.bounds.size.width);
    anim.duration       = duration;
    anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    // RANDOMIZE!!
    anim.timeOffset     = arc4random() % (int) duration;
    anim.repeatCount    = INFINITY;

    [layer removeAnimationForKey:keyPath];
    [layer addAnimation:anim forKey:keyPath];
    [_animatingLayers addObject:layer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler to use a single keyframe animation instead of a group of two separate animations.

```
- (void)addWobbleAnimationToView:(UIView *)view amount:(CGFloat)amount speed:(NSTimeInterval)speed {
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    animation.duration = 2 * speed;
    animation.values = @[ @0.0f, @(-amount), @0.0f, @(amount), @0.0f ];
    animation.keyTimes = @[ @0.0, @0.25, @0.5, @0.75, @1.0 ];
    CAMediaTimingFunction *easeOut =[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    CAMediaTimingFunction *easeIn =[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    animation.timingFunctions = @[ easeOut, easeIn, easeOut, easeIn ];
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    [view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:animation.keyPath];
}
```